# Build a Relationship

Tags: relationships

I have 3 channels

**City**

-Name of City(Title)

**University**

-Name of School(Title)
-Address
-City(Relationship Field With City Channel)

**Professor**

-Name of Professor(Title)
-University Name (Relationship field with University Channel)
-Gender
-Salary
-Experience

Now What I have to do is On City Page I have to list all University and when i click on that university then on that University Page I have to show all Professor teaching in that University

The Code I am using is

```
  {exp:channel:entries channel="university" limit="1" url_title=segment_2}
  {title}
  {address}
  <table>
  {relationship_field="universityname"}
  <tr>
  <td class="gender">{if relationship_field:gender == 'M'}<span class="male"></span>{if:else}<span class="female"></span>{/if}</td>
  <td>{relationship_field:title}</td>
  <td>{relationship_field:experience}</td>
  <td>${relationship_field:salary}</td>
  </tr>
  {/relationship_field}
  </table>
```

But for some reasons i cant get the value of Professor Channel. 
Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Professor is the one with the relationship field then **Professor > University** is a **Parent > Child** relationship. So if you're in a University (Child) entry you need to use the `parents` tag for the relationship to get the opposite relationship, so something like this should work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="university" limit="1" url_title=segment_2}
    {parents field="universityname"}
        <tr>
            <td class="gender">{if parents:gender == 'M'}<span class="male"></span>{if:else}<span class="female"></span>{/if}</td>
            <td>{parents:title}</td>
            <td>{parents:experience}</td>
            <td>${parents:salary}</td>
        </tr>
    {/parents}
```

More about parents [in the EE relationship docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/relationships.html#accessing-parents).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the relationship field that points to the University in the Professor channel is called "universityname".  If so, you are getting a bit confused about how to access the relationship field contents.

The code you want is like this:

```
  {exp:channel:entries channel="university" limit="1" url_title=segment_2}
  {title}
  {address}
  <table>
  {universityname}
  <tr>
  <td class="gender">{if universityname:gender == 'M'}<span class="male"></span>{if:else}<span class="female"></span>{/if}</td>
  <td>{universityname:title}</td>
  <td>{universityname:experience}</td>
  <td>${universityname:salary}</td>
  </tr>
  {/universityname}
  </table>
```

HTH

Comment: Sorry, but i already have tried this. This gives me following output:{universityname}{/universityname}  {universityname:title}{universityname:experience}{universityname:salary}